# Sourcing/Activating Python VirtualEnv in a Bash Script

Tags: python, linux, django, bash, unix

I am trying to write a simple script that will help me activate (source) the virtualenv and set some environment variables at the same time. Below is the current version that does not yet have any environment variables.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
    exec bash "$0" "$@"
fi

# Your script here
script_dir=`dirname $0`
cd $script_dir
/bin/bash -c ". ./django-env/bin/activate; exec /bin/bash -i"
```

The trouble with this script is two-fold.

1. When I run it - seemingly successfully as it changes the command line prefix to `(django-env)` - it is missing the `My-Computer-Name:` in front of it. Obviously, it is an indication of something as I typically have `(django-env) My-Computer-Name:` as the prefix.
2. It does not activate the virtualenv properly. Namely, when I check `which python`, I am notified that the virtualenv Python is used. On the other hand, when I check for `which pip` or `which python3`, the global system's Python is used.

What can I do to fix these things and have the environment be activated?

Comment: Don't run in a sub-shell - remove `/bin/bash -c`, either straight `. ./django-env/...` or `source ./django-env/..`. How are you running the script?

Comment: I was running `source script.sh`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel - try [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Does it give tools to work with environment variables? That is what I am doing. The task in question is just a quick aside.

Comment: There are hooks for all operations (creation, activation etc.) so you can manipulate env vars from there (hooks are basically bash scripts).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem with `exec /bin/bash -i` — the executed bash could run `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` that change the current environment.

Instead of a shell script that executes shells upon shells you better create an alias or a shell function:

```
django_activate() {
    cd $1
    . ./django-env/bin/activate
}
```

Put it in `.bashrc` so it will be available in all shells and run as `django_activate $venv_dir`; for example `django_activate ~/projects/work`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what I intended it to do. I run it with `source script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ]
then
    exec bash "$0" "$@"
fi

# Your script here
script_dir=`dirname $0`
cd $script_dir
/bin/bash -c ". ./django-env/bin/activate"
```